# Jenny does trig ids A times faster than Sam, Sam does trig ids B faster than Cal. Jenny is AB faster than Cal. How does this relate to chain rule

Tags: calculus

I am a calculus student.  I am doing work with derivatives.  I am not sure how to find the equation for the word problem.

If Jenny does trig identities A times faster than Sam and Sam does trig
identities B times faster than Cal, then Jenny does trig identities AB times faster than Cal
How is this little story related to the chain rule?

I did some research and think a decent start to finding the answer is to use a right triangle and the Pythagorean Theorem.

$A^2+B^2=C^2$ or  $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}=C$

I could add time as the variable into the formula and convert it to function notation. $(t) \sqrt{A^2+B^2}=f(t)$

This is not the chain rule.  This is the constant rule and the power rule.
Constant rule = $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}  \frac{d}{dx} t$   The derivative then is $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$

Another approach I had was to think about three people doing trigonometry problems parallel.  The parallel lines would be, line1= Jenny to Sam (problems per minute faster), line 2 = Sam to Cal (problems per minute faster).

Total problems per minute(t) = line1(t)line2(t).  Or, more simply state $f(t) = AB(t^2)$

I started to substitute numbers into this equation and realized that this is not right.  It also doesn't address the chain rule, this again is the constant derivative rule and the power derivative rule.

How to start thinking about the chain rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Introduction to derivatives:**

A derivative is similar to a ratio.

Let's say that there is a physical quantity $Y$ whose value depends on another physical quantity $X$.

Since the value of $Y$ depends on the value of $X$, when $X$ changes, $Y$ will also change.

Let's say $X$ changes by a value $\Delta X$, and this causes a change in $Y$ by a value $\Delta Y$.

Now, we must assume that $Y$ varies smoothly with $X$.

This means that if $X$ changes by a very small amount, $Y$ also changes by a very small amount.

As the change $\Delta X$ gets smaller and smaller, the change $\Delta Y$ also gets smaller and smaller. And because we assumed that $Y$ varies smoothly with $X$, you'll notice that the ratio $\frac{\Delta Y}{\Delta X}$ doesn't change much after a certain point. In fact, the ratio will start approaching a constant value. And this constant value is called the derivative of $Y$ with respect to $X$, and is denoted by $\frac{dY}{dX}$ instead of $\frac{\Delta Y}{\Delta X}$.

**The chain rule:**

Now in your question, we have three dependent variables, i.e., the number of problems solved by Jenny, the number of problems solved by Sam, and the number of problems solved by Cal. And we have one independent variable, i.e., the amount of time in which the problems were solved.

Let's denote the total number of problems solved by Jenny, Sam, and Cal as $J$, $S$, and $C$ respectively. Let the time elapsed since the start be $t$.

Now in a given interval of time $\Delta t$, the number of additional problems solved by Jenny, Sam, and Cal are $\Delta J$, $\Delta S$, and $\Delta C$ respectively.

In this interval, the rates of problem solving are $\frac{\Delta J}{\Delta t}$, $\frac{\Delta S}{\Delta t}$, and $\frac{\Delta C}{\Delta t}$.

Since Jenny does trig identities A times faster than Sam and Sam does trig identities B times faster than Cal, we can write:

$\frac{\Delta J}{\Delta t}=A\frac{\Delta S}{\Delta t}$ and $\frac{\Delta S}{\Delta t}=B\frac{\Delta C}{\Delta t}$

Alternatively, for a given time interval $\Delta t$, Jenny is $A$ times faster than Sam if she can solve $A$ times more problems than him. Same for Sam and Cal.

$\implies \frac{\Delta J}{\Delta S}=A$ and $\frac{\Delta S}{\Delta C}=B$

We can multiply these ratios to see that:

$$\frac{\Delta J}{\Delta S}\frac{\Delta S}{\Delta C}=AB$$
$$\implies \frac{\Delta J}{\Delta C} = AB$$

Which means that in a given time interval $\Delta t$, Jenny can solve $AB$ times more problems than Cal. This means that she is $AB$ times faster than him. This makes intuitive sense.

Now as $\Delta t$ gets smaller, $\Delta J$, $\Delta S$, and $\Delta C$ also get smaller.

The ratio $\frac{\Delta J}{\Delta S}$, starts approaching the derivative of $J$ with respect to $S$, i.e., $\frac{dJ}{dS}$.

Similarly, the ratios $\frac{\Delta S}{\Delta C}$ and $\frac{\Delta J}{\Delta C}$ start approaching $\frac{dS}{dC}$ and $\frac{dJ}{dC}$.

These derivatives still denote the rates at which Jenny, Sam, and Cal solve problems. But now we calculate the rates over a very small interval of time, to reach the instantaneous rates.

The equation:
$$\frac{\Delta J}{\Delta S}\frac{\Delta S}{\Delta C}=AB$$
is still valid, but now we use derivatives instead of ratios.
$$\frac{dJ}{dS}\frac{dS}{dC}=AB$$
$$\implies\frac{dJ}{dC}=AB$$

As you can see, $\frac{dJ}{dC} = \frac{dJ}{dS}\frac{dS}{dC}$. And this is exactly what the chain rule is trying to say.

*The derivative of J with respect to C is the product of the derivative of J with respect to S and the derivative of S with respect to C.*

Comment: Thanks, this helps.  I learned a ton.  I would like to leave it at that but I also am wondering how fast is Jenny?  What type of equation can I plug into the chain rule to find her speed?

Comment: @Benp404 If we know how fast any one of the three is, we can find out how fast the other two are. For now, we just know the ratios of the speeds: Jenny is $A$ times faster than Sam and Sam is $B$ times faster than Cal. The ratio of their speeds is $AB:B:1$, but we don't know the common factor yet.

Comment: Thanks.  One last question, in your experience have you ever been asked to make a formula using the rules of the derivative?  Up until now I have been finding roots of the derivative as a way to find maximum and minimum.  But, I have not yet been asked to derive an entire formula.  I only have to locate points.

Comment: It really depends on your which course or exam you are studying for. "Making a formula" using the rules of the derivative isn't a standard question that I've seen anywhere. But the rules of derivatives (sum, product, chain, etc.) are still incredibly important when you're differentiating non-standard functions or functions that are a combination of multiple standard functions.